# Why is first HttpClient.GetAsync call extremely slow in my C# asp form app?

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpclient

The first call is taking 10-15 seconds, all successive calls takes less than a second. There are multiple similar questions on stackoverflow but none of the answers reduced that time.

As part of an asp webMethod, I'm calling an external API (facebook) with HttpClient. I've made sure that the HttpClient is set and initialized only once on applications startup instead of creating a new object for every request to my webMethod. I've made sure to disable proxy usage (both on the object level and as part of my web.config). The specific line that hangs for 10 seconds on the first call is the GetAsync. I call multiple endpoints which are all really fast once the first one goes through so I doubt this is related to any sort of cache.

Here's how I initialize my httpClient:

```
private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

public FacebookClient()
{
    _httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler
    {
        UseProxy = false,
        Proxy = null,
    });

    _httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/");
    _httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);

    _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders
        .Accept
        .Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
}
```

Here's the call:

```
public async Task<T> GetAsync<T>(string accessToken, string appsecret_proof, string endpoint, string args = null)
{
    HttpResponseMessage response;

    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(appsecret_proof))
    {
        // First call hangs for 10 seconds.
        response = await _httpClient.GetAsync($"{endpoint}?access_token={accessToken}&{args}").ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

[...]
```

Which is called from:

```
public async Task<TokenDebug> GetTokenDebugInfoAsync(string inputToken, string accessToken)
{
    var result = await _facebookClient.GetAsync<dynamic>(
        accessToken, 
        String.Empty, 
        "debug_token", 
        $"input_token={inputToken}&access_token={accessToken}").ConfigureAwait(false);
[...]
```

Comment: Maybe some kind of security software? I have had the same problem with TrendMicro and WCF.

Comment: Your code looks fine to me. Have you used a tool like Fiddler to see what's happening lower in the network stack? I agree with Christian, it sounds like something outside of your app.

Comment: Yeah, it does seems like something external. I'll try fiddler and maybe wireshark to see what goes on the wire.

Comment: Have you tried issuing the calls from a regular browser?

Comment: Yes. No issues there.

Comment: Weird i'm getting this problem too to my own API layer ... in postman the call takes 100ms ish, in aspnet core from a controller action 3 to 5 seconds.

Comment: I found this: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/13551

Comment: Did you found solution on this? ...

Comment: @Merian I did not. I no longer work for this project so I can't tell if it was ever resolved. The location suffered ridiculously congested internet so maybe that was just that. Using IIS didn't help either.

I never encountered the issue with my modern netcore 2.1/2.2 software.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if you solved it yet. But I had a similar issue internal in our company. It turned out do be a faulty IPv6 entry in our DNS that caused the delay.